# Source for teaching graph theory

Tags: graph-theory, education, online-resources

Does anyone have any good sources to teach upper primary so grade 7 students basics on graph theory? The only ones I can find are for like upper middle school and high school, and having trouble finding friendly sources for grade 7 students. I would appreciate the sources if any is provided.

Comment: You would probably have much better luck asking this question on the Math Education StackExchange.  Click on the icon to the far right of the title bar to get a link there.

Comment: https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1233494/what-does-inversion-mean